# Can two JButton have the same mouse clicked event function?

Tags: java, swing, listener, jbutton

I am developing a calculator in Java language. The problem is that, i put ten buttons for digits(0,1,2..9) and i want that when i clicked one of them, all perform the same mouse clicked function. Is it possible? In netbeans, it does not let me do that, or i couldnt achieve. Thank you for helping.

Comment: Don't use MouseListeners for JButtons except for some unusual circumstances. As the answer shows, use ActionListeners.

Comment: well, I doubt you want the listener to do the _same_ thing for all of the buttons ;-)

Comment: @kleopatra: sometimes using the same listener for different buttons can save you from repeat a lot of code..

Comment: @Overbose - yeah, sure, sometimes we all want travel back in time and code Assembler again ;-) If going for a _lower_ abstraction produces duplicates, something is severly wrong with the program architecture

Comment: @kleopatra: always depend on what you are doing. For example in my last work I have different button in my GUI that should do the exactly same thing. One button in the toolbar, one in a JDialog, one inside the menu.. I can share the same actionlistener beetwen this button without doing nothing wrong. The action is the same.

Comment: @Overbose - no, the Action is _not_ the same, it's "extended" :-) It has state to which the corresponding button state is bound, and a guarantee to keep the button state synchronized.

Comment: @kleopatra: yes you are right..in fact checking my code I noticed I was extending AbstractAction

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. Add the same listener to both buttons you are using.
For example, suppose you are using actionListener then:

```
public class ListenerClass implements Action{

     @override 
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         //here retrieve information on which button has generated the event
     }
}

ListenerClass listener = new ListenerClass();
JButton first = new JButton(); 
JButton second = new JButton();
first.addActionListener(listener);
second.addActionListener(listener);
```

Comment: +1 especially for using the listener that works for both mouse *&* keyboard.

Comment: +1 for using the listener that is inactivated if the JButton has been disabled.

Comment: @kleopatra can you please elaborate why use of Action is more appropriate? I do not see it clearly why? So far I can see that you can use both in the same way. Please correct me and link to a resource which would help me finally get it once and for all :)

Comment: @kleopatra great thanks you are completely right. Action should always be used. Especially that if you really want to use it as if it was an ActionListener (i.e, ignoring its state) you can by calling addActionListener() instead of setAction(). Didn't know it --- apparently I must have ignored the Action section as the same as ActionListener when reading the doc.

Comment: @0verbose you should seriously edit the code in your answer. 0) the ListenerClass is missing class word in front. 1) listener methods are public and Override annotation wouldn't hurt. 2) use Action. 3) It is all good to practice and advertise good habits. I understand that some of these errors are result of rapid typing outside an IDE, but now that the time is not chasing you :) please make the corrections until then -1.

Comment: @0verbose cool one tiny thing which is add public in front of the actionPerformed method.

Comment: @0verbose great +1 for the solution and respecting the necessity of the corrections. Good luck